# Making the military tag its own thing

Tags: discussion, feature-request, specific-tag

I am in the process of fleshing out a question about the way that the military is organized and interacts with governmental structures in a part of my conworld.

Now there is a [warfare](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warfare) tag `For questions related to the effects of certain circumstances, conditions, or locality changes on war.` and in its current form the [military](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military) tag is a synonym for [warfare](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warfare) (which seems ill-fitting **at best**). But my question is about the military as a structure/body, not about war itself.

I propose hereby to repurpose the [military](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military) tag as follows:

[military](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military) `For questions relating to the structure or relations regarding a fictional military or its parts`

---

The goal of this meta-question is to address the need perceived by myself and to see if this is a shared need. Also it aims to provide a way to discuss pros/cons of repurposing the existing synonym into a new tag and to search for alternatives if needed.

Comment: do you have the rep to make a new tag?

Comment: @TunaDragon the tag currently exists as a synonym for [tag:warfare] which I think is ill-fitting, thus this question

Comment: ah I see your point.

Comment: Would modifying Military to Military-organization or something similar help spell things out?

Comment: @James the issue is more along the lines that the [tag:military] tag currently is set to be a synonym for [tag:warfare] which doesn't really make much sense as the noun usually is stronger than the adjective

Answer (score 2):

I've broken the tag synonym between [military](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military) and [warfare](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warfare) and added the wiki excerpt from the question.  I suggest that interested parties review the questions on each tag and retag anything that needs it (try not to totally slam the front page, though), along with editing the tag wikis.

Comment: Well, there are exactly 3 questions using the [tag:military] tag, so it should be a jiffy; I'll have a look at them soon I get time for it and will propose the necessary edit

Comment: It's possible that some of the warfare questions are really military, post-split.  But yeah, checking the three military questions shouldn't be hard and is more important.

Comment: Sounds like a fun weekend

Answer (score 0):

It seems the sentiment is shared by others. But I seem not to be able to make the changes myself, as:

**Creating Tag Synonyms** (I assume also the editing of these) requires **1250 rep**

**Editing Tag Wikis** requires **1500 rep**

Hence I'll tag this discussion for moderator attention :)

Comment: Good idea. I'm on an iPad just now or I'd do it. Possibly in an hour or so, though.